# PDO Fetchcolumn gives undefined

Tags: php, sql, pdo, fetch

I'm doing a `SELECT` from a database and getting values for field `name` and `level`, but when I fetch the data I only get the `name`. I've tried to do the query directly into MySQL and it works, so I think it is a PHP problem. Here's my code:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name,level FROM user WHERE id = :id");

/*** bind the parameters ***/
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

/*** execute the prepared statement ***/
$stmt->execute();

/*** check for a result ***/
$phpro_username = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$phpro_level = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
```

The `$phpro_username` gives me the `name`, but `$phpro_level` returns `undefined`.
I looked at the documentation and it's supposed to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just select 2 columns name & level.
In the first fetchColumn you fetch the first column, which is the name column.
But in the second fetchColumn you want to fetch the next column after skipping one column, so it would be FALSE.
try this :
    $phpro_username = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $phpro_level = $stmt->fetchColumn();

```
public string PDOStatement::fetchColumn ([ int $column_number = 0 ] )
Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.
```

or

you can do this

```
/*** check for a result ***/  
$phppro = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$phpro_username = $phppro['name'];  
$phpro_level = $phppro['level'];
```

Comment: The first one didn't work. But the second one worked like a charm! Thanks!